# Cannot convert or cast a List into another one using as operator or simple cast

Tags: c#

Let's code a program sorting *friendy* and *nasty* people. All are *characters* and have a *name*.

We can represent this as follow :

```
interface ICharacter
{
    string GetName();
}

class Character : ICharacter
{
    private readonly string name;

    public Character(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public string GetName()
    {
        return this.name;
    }
}


class Friendly : Character
{
    public Friendly(string name) 
        : base(name)
    {

    }
}

class Nasty : Character
{
    public Nasty(string name)
        : base(name)
    {

    }
}
```

Now let's declare and store our characters into a Dictionary this way :

```
Dictionary<Type, IList<ICharacter>> characters = new Dictionary<Type, IList<ICharacter>>();

characters.Add(typeof(Friendly), new List<ICharacter>() { new Friendly("friendly1"), new Friendly("friendly2") });
characters.Add(typeof(Nasty), new List<ICharacter>() { new Nasty("nasty1"), new Nasty("nasty2") });
```

Now we can code a method extracting all friendy people from dictionary as a list of friendly people and NOT a list of characters :

```
 public static List<Friendly> GetFriendlyPeople(Dictionary<Type, IList<ICharacter>> allPeople)
 {
     if (allPeople.TryGetValue(typeof(Friendly), out IList<ICharacter> friendly)) {
         return friendly as List<Friendly>; //(List<Friendly>)friendly the same result
     }
     return new List<Friendly>();
 }
```

Finally, we can call the method GetFriendlyPeople :

```
List<Friendly> friends = GetFriendlyPeople(characters);
```

But the return value is *null*. I tried several combination using interface or not and it's the same result.

Comment: A `List<ICharacter>`, by necessity, can never be a `List<Friendly>`. Because whilst it was still a `List<ICharacter>`, it would have allowed someone to add a `Nasty` to it. Nothing in the type system would have prevented that.

Comment: `List<T>`'s lack of covariance strikes again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your dictionary you have two types, `Friendly` and `Nasty`.

Th list in Dictionary is a list of `ICharacter` it not one type its multiable types, that why you gets null.

Try this and you will get an exception that will explane it too you.

```
 return friendly.Cast<Friendly>().ToList()// here you will get now an exception.
```

If you want to have your `Friendly` items is still possible.
try this code.

```
return friendly.Where(x=> x is Friendly).Cast<Friendly>().ToList(); // here you will get your items.
```

Comment: The first proposition works and never throw any exception in my exemple because I sort my characters correctly at the beginning when I initialize my dictionary (it's juste an example). I think I could have used the second proposition if I stored all the characters in a simple list of ICharacter as container. Thank you very much !